# How to get this inside edge to Bevel?

Tags: modeling, bevel

I have a right angle inside edge that I want to bevel.  However, when I try and use the bevel tool it just slides straight down the z-axis and does not actually create a bevel there.

[PROJECT FILE](https://www.dropbox.com/s/nckdfk7knd2x14z/Bevel%20How.blend?dl=0)

Would love some direction. This is the edge I'm trying to bevel:
[image]

And this is what happens when I use the bevel tool (Ctrl+B):
[image]

Answer (score 1):

OK so I just tinkered and figured this out on my own.  I wanted to leave this here in case anyone comes across this same issue.

The problem is that I had multiple edges in the same place.  This was a result of the Spin tool I had used to extrude the handle of the mug.

The solution was to select each edge and choose **Mesh>Clean Up>Merge By Distance**, set to the minimum, and 'Unselected' enabled:

[image]

And now it works as expected:

[image]